# How to correctly position JButtons and size JTextFields?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, layout-manager, jtextfield

I am trying to create a password vault, but whenever I try to run it, the `JTextField`s are extremely small and the panel is somewhat being covered by the `JTable`.

I have tried playing with the dimensions and the positions of the `GridBag` but nothing works.

This is for my IB Computer Science IA. Any help would be great.

```
    JFrame passwordVault;
    JTable passwordTable;
    Object[] columnNames = {"Name of Application", "Application Password", "Description"};
    JTextField appName, appPass, appDesc;
    JButton add, delete, update;
    JLabel nameOfApp, passOfApp, descOfApp;

    passwordVault = new JFrame("Password Vault");
    passwordTable = new JTable();
    JPanel passwordPanel = new JPanel();

    DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel();
    tableModel.setColumnIdentifiers(columnNames);
    passwordTable.setModel(tableModel);

    nameOfApp = new JLabel("App Name: ");
    passOfApp = new JLabel("App Password: ");
    descOfApp = new JLabel("Description: ");    

    appName = new JTextField();
    appPass = new JTextField();
    appDesc = new JTextField();

    add = new JButton("Add");
    delete = new JButton("Delete");
    update = new JButton("Update");  

    appName.setBounds(400, 220, 100, 25);
    appPass.setBounds(400, 250, 100, 25);
    appDesc.setBounds(400, 280, 100, 25);

    add.setBounds(530, 220, 100, 25);
    update.setBounds(530, 250, 100, 25);
    delete.setBounds(530, 280, 100, 25);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(passwordTable);
    scrollPane.setBounds(0, 0, 1000, 200);
    passwordVault.add(scrollPane);

    passwordPanel.add(add);
    passwordPanel.add(update);
    passwordPanel.add(delete);

    passwordPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    passwordPanel.add(nameOfApp, new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0,
        GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
    passwordPanel.add(appName, new GridBagConstraints(1, 0, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0,
        GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
    passwordPanel.add(passOfApp, new GridBagConstraints(0, 1, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0,
        GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
    passwordPanel.add(appPass, new GridBagConstraints(1, 1, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0,
        GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
    passwordPanel.add(descOfApp, new GridBagConstraints(0, 2, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0,
        GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
    passwordPanel.add(appDesc, new GridBagConstraints(2, 2, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0,
        GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
    passwordPanel.add(add, new GridBagConstraints(3, 3, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0,
            GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
    passwordPanel.add(update, new GridBagConstraints(4, 3, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0,
            GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
    passwordPanel.add(delete, new GridBagConstraints(5, 3, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0,
            GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));

    passwordVault.add(passwordPanel);
    passwordVault.setSize(1000,500);
    passwordVault.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    passwordVault.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Don't use setBounds(). Use setPreferred Size()

Comment: 1) *"the `JTextField`s are extremely small"* The appropriate size of a text field can be suggested by specifying a number of columns (related to characters it is expected to display) in the constructor. 2) Provide ASCII art or a drawing of the desired layout at minimum size and when expanded (to show where extra space should be assigned). 3) When asking questions, add a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an edited version of your program that formats the layout how I think you were trying to:

```
        JFrame passwordVault;
        JTable passwordTable;
        Object[] columnNames = {"Name of Application", "Application Password", "Description"};
        JTextField appName, appPass, appDesc;
        JButton add, delete, update;
        JLabel nameOfApp, passOfApp, descOfApp;

        passwordVault = new JFrame("Password Vault");
        passwordTable = new JTable();
        JPanel passwordPanel = new JPanel();

        DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel();
        tableModel.setColumnIdentifiers(columnNames);
        passwordTable.setModel(tableModel);

        nameOfApp = new JLabel("App Name: ");
        passOfApp = new JLabel("App Password: ");
        descOfApp = new JLabel("Description: ");    

        appName = new JTextField();
        appPass = new JTextField();
        appDesc = new JTextField();

        add = new JButton("Add");
        delete = new JButton("Delete");
        update = new JButton("Update");  

        // Used setPreferredSize and setLocation instead of setBounds
        appName.setLocation(new Point(400, 220));
        appName.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 25));
        appPass.setLocation(new Point(400, 250));
        appPass.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 25));
        appDesc.setLocation(new Point(400, 280));
        appDesc.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 25));

        add.setLocation(new Point(530, 220));
        add.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 25));
        update.setLocation(new Point(530, 250));
        update.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 25));
        delete.setLocation(new Point(530, 280));
        delete.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 25));

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(passwordTable);
        scrollPane.setBounds(0, 0, 1000, 200);

        // Create a JPanel to contain the scrollPane and passwordPanel
        JPanel framePanel = new JPanel();
        framePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));

        framePanel.add(scrollPane);

        passwordPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        passwordPanel.add(nameOfApp, new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0,
            GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
        passwordPanel.add(appName, new GridBagConstraints(1, 0, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0,
            GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
        passwordPanel.add(passOfApp, new GridBagConstraints(0, 1, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0,
            GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
        passwordPanel.add(appPass, new GridBagConstraints(1, 1, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0,
            GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
        passwordPanel.add(descOfApp, new GridBagConstraints(0, 2, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0,
            GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
        passwordPanel.add(appDesc, new GridBagConstraints(1, 2, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0,
            GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
        passwordPanel.add(add, new GridBagConstraints(0, 3, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0,
                GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
        passwordPanel.add(update, new GridBagConstraints(1, 3, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0,
                GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
        passwordPanel.add(delete, new GridBagConstraints(2, 3, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0,
                GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));

        framePanel.add(passwordPanel);

        // Add the framePanel (which contains the other 2 panels) to the JFrame
        passwordVault.add(framePanel);

        passwordVault.setSize(1000,500);
        passwordVault.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        passwordVault.setVisible(true);
```

So, the main changes were:

1. Used `setPreferredSize` and `setLocation`, instead of `setBounds` for the `JTextField`s and `JButton`s
2. Created a main `JPanel` (called it `framePanel`) to contain the `scrollPane` and `passwordPanel`, and then added `framePanel` to the `JFrame`

It helps to organize the different elements in a `JFrame` by creating a main `JPanel`, instead of just adding multiple `JPanel`s to the `JFrame` itself. That way, the one main `JPanel` decides the overall layout of the frame.

Comment: Thank you so much, do you know how to align the buttons with the other elements? Because right now, the buttons are about 50 or so pixels to the right of the JTextFields and JLabels.

Comment: Honestly you were such a big help! Thank you so much, the code works perfectly now!

Comment: Minus one. Please stop providing layout advice until you realize why we should avoid explicitly setting the size and location of components.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Bruh, like I don't care, but this was 3 years ago...